# Google Earth Pro IOS app not opening exported kml file

Tags: qgis, raster, kml, google-earth

I classified an image in QGIS using the dzetsaka plugin. I then exported it as a GeoTiff with the Rendered image Output mode selected, so that I could see it in Google Earth Pro. Otherwise, the raster only displays 0's and 1's. I made sure that my CRS was projected to EPSG: 4326 - WGS 84 since that is what Google Earth Pro is set to. I imported the file into GEP and used the Super Overlay process. Everything to this point works.

I then saved the file as a .kml and uploaded it into my drive to be uploaded into my GEP phone app (iphone 7). I am able to upload the file with the app, but it does not zoom into the correct position, nor shows what I see on the desktop GEP (image below). I tried creating a polygon within GEP on my desktop and my phone GEP app does recognize the file and works perfectly. I also noticed that my polygon kml is 2KB and my raster kml is 500 bytes.

I also tried vectorising my classified raster within QGIS, but because my resolution is so high, the process is taking 10+ hours and that is not sufficient (plus, it would crash on me every time). So I'd really like to stick with working with rasters.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The issues you're seeing sound like the image wasn't rendered correctly.  Really make sure that you used the rendered output when exporting, and double-check that the resulting image is a 3-band RGB GeoTiff. The other thing to check usually is that the image isn't too large, but if you're processing it into a SuperOverlay, then that should be ok.  Maybe try a scaled or cropped import first to see if that works?

Comment: The tif isn't going to be a typical 3-band RGB because it's a classified image. So what you are seeing in the image is one specific type of grass. Everything else has been set to transparent. I've had a couple "larger" kml files crash my GEP app, but this kml file simply does not load. It's like there is no data in the file (though there is).

Comment: The image above is my GEP on my desktop, this is exactly what I want. I need that in the phone GEP app. I'll give cropping a try.

Comment: Yes, your starting image can be classified and not 3-band RGB.  But since Google Earth can only import & display 3-band RGB images, you need to use a rendered output version of the image for importing into Google Earth, as I think you already did.  If it worked in GEPro, then that part should be fine.  If you're only having issues loading it in iOS, then it's likely a limitation of the iOS app not supporting the all the necessary KML tags or file size.  Might you be able to share the file so we can help debug?

Comment: That is correct. How do I share the file?

Comment: Put it somewhere public and provide the link.... your web server? Google Drive? Dropbox? etc?

Comment: Sorry, here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ddldkblc8papoc/output_rendered.tif?dl=0

Comment: Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: I think it is simply just too large (2.5GB)